# How to Avoid Abusing the Terminology of Interpretations and Representations With Respect to Formal Languages?

Tags: notation, terminology, formal-languages, article-writing

I find myself floundering in terminology, with the result that I fear the article I am writing will only appeal to readers afflicted with masochistic tendencies.  At the very least, there is the danger that by redefining such terms as "interpretation" and "representation," I risk being accused of muddying the waters. Can any soul brave and kind enough to endure the following torrent of words give this amateur mathematician advice on how he might reframe the associated concepts properly using already-established terminology?  Even if you do not have the inclination to wade through the entire thing, I would greatly appreciate any assistance, no matter how modest.

I foolishly begin by proposing my own definition of a word already having an accepted definition in mathematics, because my deficiency of mathematical sophistication prevents me from understanding the nuances of the accepted definition and I fear growing senile before I can correct the deficiency:

> **Definition 2.1.** Let $L$ be a language, and let $S$ be a set.  If there exists some surjective function $f: L \rightarrow S$,
> then we will call the triplet $(L,S,f)$ *an interpretation of L as S*, specifically *the interpretation of L as S according to f*, and we may say any of the following:
>
> - $L$ interpreted according to $f$ is $S$ (equivalently: $L$ is the *underlying language* in the interpretation $(L,S,f)$).
> - $S$ is $L$ interpreted according to $f$ (equivalently: $S$ is the *target set* in the interpretation $(L,S,f)$).
> - $f$ interprets $L$ as $S$ (equivalently: $f$ is the *evaluation function* in the interpretation $(L,S,f)$).
>
> *Remark.* For example, let $B$ denote the set of nonempty strings over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ and let ${f : B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}}$, where $f({b})$ is the nonnegative integer corresponding to $b$ such that the latter is regarded as a word in unsigned binary.  Then ${(B,\mathbb{N}, f)}$ is the interpretation of $B$ as the set of natural numbers according to  $f$.  Now consider ${g : B \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}}$, where $g({b})$ is the integer corresponding to $b$ such that the latter is regarded as a word in 2s-complement binary.  Then ${(B,\mathbb{Z}, g)}$ is the interpretation of $B$ as the set of integers according to $g$.  Thus we have an illustration of a single language underlying multiple interpretations.

As if the preceding were not excruciating enough, I force my reader to endure another definition, this time pertaining to members of sets rather than the sets themselves:

> The following definition allows us to speak of interpretations in terms of set members as well.
>
> **Definition 2.2.**  Let $(L,S,f)$ be an interpretation.  For any $l \in L$, let $s \in S$ where $s = f(l)$. Then we may say any of the following:
>
> - $s$ is $l$ interpreted according to $f$.
> - $l$ interpreted according to $f$ is $s$.
> - $f$ interprets $l$ as $s$.

Not satisfied with having intruded on the terminology of interpretations, I presumptuously redefine representations:

> Sometimes the terminology of interpretations becomes awkward, resulting in a surfeit of passive participles  ("*l* interpreted as..."; "*l* interpreted according to...").  We may remedy this to some extent by making use of the following definition.
>
> **Definition 2.3.** Let $(L, S, f)$ be an interpretation,  and let the ordered pair $(l,s)$ be in the graph of $f$.  Then we say *l represents s in $(L, S, f)$*.  If we do not wish to mention a particular interpretation (as for example when the interpretation would be clear from the context), we may simply say *l represents s*, implying some interpretation exists such that $l$ represents $s$ in that interpretation.
>
> In addition to speaking of members of languages representing members of sets, we can speak of languages representing sets.
>
> **Definition 2.4.** If $(L, S, f)$ is an interpretation, then we say *L represents S in $(L, S, f)$*, or, equivalently, *$L$ is a representation of $S$ in $(L, S, f)$*.  In cases where we do not wish to mention a specific interpretation, we may simply say $L$ represents $S$, or, equivalently, *$L$ is a representation of $S$*.

A particularly sad aspect of all this is that none of the above definitions is what my paper is "about"; they are only devices meant to enable me to articulate what my paper is about.

Can someone help me out of this morass of my own making?

Comment: Neither of your definitions sound crazy, but I don't know what the normal definitions are. I tried to google "interpretation" but got many results. Could you link to the accepted definitions you're having trouble with?

Comment: Part of this morass does seem to be of your own making.  For example, why do you say “let the ordered pair $(l,s)$ be in the graph of $f$” when you could just say “let $f(l)=s$”?  My impression is that you are using a large amount of verbiage to explain a very simple notation. The one example you give is quite clear: “For example, consider the usual interpretation of nonempty strings of binary digits as integers.  One such interpretation has $f({\tt 011010}) = 26$ and $f({\tt 1111111}) = 127$”.

Comment: You also don't need to consider $\langle L, S, f\rangle$ as being different somehow from $f$ itself.  The function $f$ carries with it information about its domain and codomain, so you can just as easily say that $f:L\to S$ is itself the interpretation.

Comment: Also I don't think your twos-complement example actually works unless you either prescribe a width or require that positive numbers always be written with a leading zero.

Comment: @preferred_anon, part of the problem is that I myself do not know what the "normal" definitions are.  When I searched Wikipedia, the following seemed to contain the most relevant, or at least the most explicit, definition of what is meant by the term *interpretation*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory).  But the definition, to the extent I can understand it, somehow seems too "heavyweight" for my purposes, as one of my goals is to make my article accessible to as general an audience as possible.  By the way, thank you for taking time during the holidays to reply!

Comment: @MarkDominus, verbosity is one of my greatest shortcomings, and I find myself struggling with it constantly.  I will thus give serious consideration to your suggestion that I abandon the triplet notation. But there is a part of me that wants to retain it, as my article concerns an alternative to positional numeration systems for representing numbers, and the triplet notation serves to reinforce the sense that the interpretation is a system of representation, calling out as it does the language representing the set, the represented set, and the mapping from the former to the latter.

Comment: @MarkDominus, you are indeed correct in your observation that my 2's-complement example is flawed.  Thank you for the catch, and also thank you for taking time during the holidays to answer the questions of a struggling would-be mathematician.

Comment: Verbosity is something you can fix.  Practice editing.  After you write each sentence, go back and remove the unnecessary words.  For example, “I will thus give serious consideration to …” could  become “I will seriously consider…”.